# Javascript Form Variable Place Holder

Tags: javascript, forms

I am currently creating a form that when filled out by the user, will place all of the form information in to predesigned documents.  For instance, a user will fill out their first name, last name, address, etc., and the documents below the form are automatically populated with the form information that has been entered.  All of that is working perfectly.  However, I would like the textboxes that I am using in the document to hold the variables to remove the extra white space that is left over when a variable is entered.  Some names may be longer than others and I do not want extra white space in my documents.  Is there any way to make my textboxes have a width based on the variable that is contained in it?

Comment: You should have to try user self before asking question. please add code snippet what you have done stackoverflow can provide solution to your problem we are here to help not for giving you a code. please provide code snippet

Comment: I have been trying myself for over a week now.  I'm not looking for code, just a guide in the right general direction.  A code snippet in this instance wouldn't have helped any if I don't have anything that is remotely working.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's no CSS way to do it, however you can use JavaScript and do a pretty good estimate. Something like this.

```
var el = document.getElementById('myInput');

el.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
    e.target.style.width = e.target.value.length * 10 + 'px';
});
```

The logic here is that whenever you press a key while the input is selected, the callback will find the text's length and resize the element to be the character length * 10 pixels wide. This is not super precise as character pixel width varies.

Comment: This is a great idea, and I truly appreciate the help.  Let me give this a shot and see if helps accomplish what I have in mind.  Thanks so much for your time and help.